# Passing username and password to .NET HttpWebRequest via URI does not work

Tags: .net, http, httpwebrequest, uri

Running the following code:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://username:password@savanttools.com/test-http-status-codes.asp?code=401");
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

... and inspecting the request using Wireshark reveals that no authorization is attempted by my client (the url is a simple service that will always return 401).

This code sends an authorization header after the initial challenge:

```
var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://username:password@savanttools.com/test-http-status-codes.asp?code=401");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Using the `System.Uri` class has no effect. Why is the username and password passed in the url not used for authentication?

(I'm aware of [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like) on passing the authorization header without an initial challenge, but that is not the issue at hand)

**EDIT** I should add that it is fairly easy to work around this limitation, for example with this bit of code (add url un-escaping to taste), I'm just curious as to why you have to do this:

```
var userInfo = request.Address.UserInfo;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInfo) && userInfo.Contains(':'))
{
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userInfo.Split(':').First(), userInfo.Split(':').Last());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `HttpWebRequest` class does not utilize the credentials in the `Uri` (per dotPeek).

But the `FtpWebRequest` does, here is the relevant code:

```
if (this.m_Uri.UserInfo != null && this.m_Uri.UserInfo.Length != 0)
  {
    string userInfo = this.m_Uri.UserInfo;
    string userName = userInfo;
    string password = "";
    int length = userInfo.IndexOf(':');
    if (length != -1)
    {
      userName = Uri.UnescapeDataString(userInfo.Substring(0, length));
      int startIndex = length + 1;
      password = Uri.UnescapeDataString(userInfo.Substring(startIndex, userInfo.Length - startIndex));
    }
    networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
  }
```

As you can see it just attaches it to credentials, so you should just do that instead manually with a parsed `Uri`

Comment: Yeah, I have a similar bit of code -- I just don't get why HttpWebRequest ignores this...

Comment: I think due to it being a security issue.  Many browsers now ignore this as well: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489 I'd have to go back in look at previous .NET versions to see if it was ever coded to use it, but its explicitly not in 4.0